# How to create taxonomy term when creating the taxonomy through a custom plugin?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to add Taxonomy Term pragmatically when creating taxonomy. I tried adding the

```
wp_insert_term(
    'A00',   // the term 
    'we_colors'
);
```

to the `tax_color_palletes` but this is not adding the term `A00`. I am working on this snippet; how can I fix this?

```
function tax_color_palletes() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => 'Models',
        'singular_name'              => 'Model',
        'menu_name'                  => 'Models',
        'all_items'                  => 'All Models',
        'parent_item'                => 'Parent Model',
        'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent Model',
        'new_item_name'              => 'Model Name',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Model',
        'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Model',
        'update_item'                => 'Update Model Type',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate Model with commas',
        'search_items'               => 'Search Models',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove Model Type',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used Model',
        'not_found'                  => 'Model Not Found',
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'women_models', array( 'we_colors' ), $args );
    wp_insert_term(
        'A00',   // the term 
        'we_colors'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'tax_color_palletes', 0 );
```

Comment: I am facing same issue, even posted question but didnt get any answer.  In my case terms got added if taxonomy is already registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to add the `term` to your `taxonomy` or `post_type`?

In your example you register the `taxonomy` 'women_models' to the `post_type` 'we_colors'.
But then you call `wp_insert_term` (which requires a `taxonomy`) and pass it a `post_type`. Which should give you an error.

If you want to just add a `term` to a `taxonomy`, you need to pass your `taxonomy` to `wp_insert_term`.

```
wp_insert_term('A00', 'women_models');
```

If instead you are actually trying to add a term to a post_type, you should use `wp_set_object_terms` which can in turn call `wp_insert_term` itself to create new terms. You will need to get the `$object_id` first however.

```
wp_set_object_terms( $object_id, ['term_1', 'term_2'], 'taxonomy_name');
```

> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/
>   https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/
>   https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_object_terms/